# Platypush: where is the SRC folder?

Tags: python

Trying to get a thermal camera working on my raspberry pi 4. Have installed platypush. Following [these](https://platypush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platypush/plugins/camera.ir.mlx90640.html) instructions and next command is "cd PLATYPUSH_SRC_DIR"

But where is the SRC directory? I can't find it in the platypush folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's `cd $PLATYPUSH_SRC_DIR`, the `$` is significant (used to indicate an *environment variable*).

But using that is unlikely to make a difference as it is probably not set.  It looks like it is referring to the toplevel directory of the source you presumably downloaded or git cloned.